# Pandas sum of multi-indexed columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

If I have a data frame with nested headers like this:

```
              John          Joan
         Smith,   Jones,    Smith,
Index1     234      432      324
Index2     2987     234      4354
```

...how do I create a new column that sums the values of each row?
I tried `df['sum']=df['John']+df['Joan']` but that resulted in this error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

> ...how do I create a new column that sums the values of each row?

#### Solution

The sum of each row is just

```
df.sum(axis=1)
```

The trick is getting to be a new column.  You need to ensure the column you add has 2 levels of column heading.

```
df.loc[:, ('sum', 'sum')] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

I'm not happy with it, but it works.

```
         Joan   John          sum
       Smith, Jones, Smith,   sum
Index1    324    432    234   990
Index2   4354    234   2987  7575
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. How would I create the new sum column, as above, if there are some other preceding columns for which I do not want a sum? For example, if the first column is name and the second is age, how would I ignore those?

Comment: I figured out my follow-up question: First, define the set of columns to sum as a variable like this: cols=df[['a','b']]. Next, use that variable like this: df.loc[:, ('sum', 'sum')] = cols.sum(axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

Dance Party, haven't heard from you in a while.

You want to groupby, but specify a level and axis.  `axis=1` means you want to sum the rows instead of the columns.  `level=0` is the top row of the columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    ('John', 'Smith,'): [234, 2987], 
    ('John', 'Jones,'): [432, 234], 
    ('Joan', 'Smith,'): [324, 4354]}, index=['Index1', 'Index2'])

>>> df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
        Joan  John
Index1   324   666
Index2  4354  3221
```